# Possibility of running a local network server from the browser

Tags: javascript, java, android, sockets, libgdx

This question is about the basic feasibility of this project but you are welcome to recommend ideas on how it could be done. I would like to create a hosted Java web application that creates a Server in the local network of the device.

For example: You can go to example.com in your Browser and start the application that creates a server in the local network of the device (Windows-PC). Other devices (Android) can connect to the server (UDP) with an installed Android-App.

Is this concept possible? I am afraid browser security renders this level of access  impossible..

Comment: "I am afraid browser security renders this level of access impossible", you'd be correct

Comment: @George What is the next best thing you could think of?

Comment: @MiXT4PE George is correct and so is your assumption. This is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out it is not possible.

I will instead choose a local Java application that has to be installed.

Comment: It is also possible to run this server inside your game client.